# Java parser library for NetBeans

Tags: java, parsing, netbeans, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

I want to make a java application that takes java source codes as input to create and visit their Abstract Syntax Trees, so I can make some statistics out of them.

I found this java parser: https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser

My questions are:

- Is there a way to import that library into NetBeans? Maybe from a jar file?
- Are there other parsers for what I want to do?
- Is using NetBeans and java language the easiest way to do this or should I use a different IDE or different programming languages?

Answer (score 2):

Some years ago I've done a prototype to analyze Java source. 
I used this library [Recoder (manual)](http://recoder.sourceforge.net/doc/manual.html) that do the dirty work for me (parsing and building a good designed AST).

It's a jar so you can use it with any kind of IDE.

Usually I use Eclispe as Java IDE. It has its own AST model and you can consider to use Eclipse JDT [Eclipse JDT](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about NetBeans but you can create a project using maven or gradle and specify a dependency to JavaParser and you are done. It is that easy. Alternatively you may want to download the JavaParser jar from Maven central: it should not have any dependency so that would be enough.

Disclaimer: I am a contributor to JavaParser

Comment: I am quite new to github and the use of libraries, so can you explain me what maven is and how to use it?

Comment: Maven is a build system that you can use to declare dependencies.

If you create a program and configure it for Maven you can say that your program uses libraries A, B and C. Maven will download A, B, C and verify if they have dependencies. If they do also their dependencies will be download etc.

I cannot explain you how to use Maven in a comment but you can take a look here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html